# How to create a couple uitableview in swift using interface builder?

Tags: uitableview, swift

how we can create a couple of uitableview in view controller.let we have two categories of pizza like veg and non veg. how we can show veg pizza in left uitableview and non veg pizza in right uitableview. .[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create 2 UITableViews into your ViewController.

Create a TableViewController and set the Delegate and Datasource to them.

Then create 2 Tags (for each Table) and then use in every tableView method your tag identifier.

For Example:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     if(tableView.tag == 0) {
          // return count of normal pizza
     } else {
         // return count of veg pizza
     }       
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a UIViewController (not a UITableViewController) and drag two UITableViews onto it. Size them to your needs and set the constraints accordingly.

After that, you have to create a custom class for the UIViewController that handles the required TableViewDatasource protocols. Set the `Datasource` and `Delegate` properties of the UITableViews to that class.

Comment: i have already take Two UITableView. I am so confused in numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath method because in this case we have two UITableView. What should i do ?

Comment: The tableView is passed as a parameter in these functions. You can give the UITableViews identifiers in StoryBoard or distinguish between them by different tags. Thus you get a way to identify the tableView within these methods.

Comment: @VijayRawat Create outlet for both table view. And using outlet you can split table view.